# How to open Fragment on click of push notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications

> My Firebasemessagingservice class code for passing intent:

```
private void showNotification(String message){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, DrawerActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("data", message);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Registry")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_send_icon_blue)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

> My Fragment BaseActivity code in onCreate() method:

```
Intent notifyIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = notifyIntent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

       replacefragment code;

    }
```

It's not working..

Comment: pls post replace fragment code also. And edit question to mention it properly what u want to achieve

Comment: What is the problem, please ask a question ... see [ask] and explain you problem

Comment: Override `NewIntent()` method in your activity and call fragment from it.

Comment: I tried NewIntent() method but it's not working

Comment: have you checked that NewIntent() is calling or not ?

Comment: yes, It's not called

Comment: @shweta Te barabar proper check karyu che kem k hu e j use karu chu

Comment: @shweta Can I show code?

Comment: done with above code

Comment: @shweta means solve thai gayu ?

Comment: yes , it's solved..

Comment: Reason to DownVote ??

Answer (score 6):

First, in the code were you make the notification declarate the intent at the next way:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClass.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("menuFragment", "MyFragment");
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(MyClass.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Assign the intent to mBuilder

```
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Then go to the activity main and add this code in the onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}
```

Finaly add this method in MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            if(extras.containsKey("menuFragment"))
            {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detail_fragment_container, MyFragment.newInstance() ).commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent) was very important to get the activity to run onNewIntent

Answer (score 5):

You need  to send a key with intent data and check with that key and perform code like

```
private void showNotification(String message){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, DrawerActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("data", message);
     intent.putExtra("KEY", "YOUR VAL");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Registry")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_send_icon_blue)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

and chech on Activity like

```
Intent notifyIntent = getIntent();
   String extras = getIntent().getExtraString("KEY");;
    if (extras != null&&extras.equals("YOUR VAL")) {`enter code here`

       replacefragment code;

    }
```

also check onIntent change fro if activity is already open

Comment: Using what `Event` you check the `getIntent()` on `Activity`?